# google+ operations throws exception with spring social google

Tags: google-plus, spring-social-google

The method `plusOperations().getPerson(googleId)` generates the following exception:

> Could not read JSON: No enum const class
>
> ```
> org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.Person$UrlType.CONTRIBUTOR
> (through reference chain: 
>   org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.Person["urls"]->
>   org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.ProfileURL["type"]); 
> nested exception is 
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No enum const class 
> org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.Person$UrlType.CONTRIBUTOR 
> (through reference chain: 
>   org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.Person["urls"]->
>   org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.ProfileURL["type"])
> ```

Comment: The title of this question made me think you were inviting us to an event.

Comment: an issue has been opened on the github project:
https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google/issues/55